# Install watchdog and firewall on Plesk 11.5

Tags: firewall, installation, watchdog

As far as I know Plesk arrives with Firewall and Watchdog out of the box, but now I'm working on a new server with Plesk 11.5.30 and I the Extensions Management page is empty.

How can I install the watchdog and firewall modules by myself?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional Plesk modules can be installed from the shell with the Plesk autoinstaller:

```
$PRODUCT_ROOT_D/admin/sbin/autoinstaller
```

Comment: What should I do with this file? Won't it reinstall the Plesk? Thanks!

Comment: Just run it. It won't reinstall your Plesk, it will provide you with an interactive menu where you can add modules to your Plesk installation.

Comment: I ran it and chose to install the modules and then it showed that it needs 1200MB for the installation. Is it normal (altough I only chose to add those 2 modules)? Thanks again

Comment: The cause for this could be that the autoinstaller will also install the needed dependencies for your modules and Plesk microupdates.

Comment: May it reset my php / mysql or Plesk cofigurations?

Comment: no. It won't reset anything.